# What are some of the locations of virtual files that can tell me CPU temperature in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu, temperature, proc

I have a router that is running customized OpenWRT OS with a MIPS cpu. I'm trying to read CPU temperature from the virtual files such as files in /proc

There is no way to install any additional programs through apt or anything. So `lm-sensors` and `sensors` and any other software need to be installed are out of the equation.

So far I've tried
`/sys/class/thermal/` (this directory does not exist)
`/sys/bus/platform/devices/` (this one does exist, but nothing looks like cpu temp)
`/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/` (this directory does not exist)
and other directories near them.

I did not find anything that looks like CPU temperature. Can anyone give me some tips and suggestions?

Comment: Consult the SoC datasheet.

Comment: @sawdust no matter where I search, it all point to this file http://www.t-firefly.com/download/FireWRT/hardware/MT7621.pdf  It does talk about thermal of the CPU, but through out the whole document, no where does it mention how to get the information.

Comment: Instead of just 43 pages, I was thinking of hundreds or thousands of pages for a "datasheet", aka technical or programming "reference manual" by some manufacturers.  Rather than just descriptions of the SoC pins, you need detailed information on the registers of the SoC.  If you could find out what SoC sensor registers are accessible, then you could check the Linux source code to see if there are any drivers that do access this sensor data.  There's also the possibility that there simply is no temperature sensor in that SoC.  There might be an external I2C board sensor?

Comment: I see. I underestimated the amount of work needed to get this information. Thank you very much for your information.